# how can i move image all over the screen using jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I am trying to move around the image all over the screen but it only move from top to bottom and left to right and then it stops.
here is my javascript Code.

```
          $(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#p2").animate({width:300 })
        $("#p2").animate({left:'600px'})
        $("#p2").animate({top:'400px'})
        $("#p2").animate({right:'100px'})
        $("#p2").animate({bottom:'400px'})
});
});
```

here is my html

```
<img src="myimage.png" id="p2" />      
<button id="btn1">click</button>
<style>
#p2{
position:absolute;

}
</style>
```

if anyone have idea that how i can animate a image all around the screen then please help me out to solve my assign .thanks for your time .

Comment: What do you mean by all around the screen?

Comment: the Letter or image should revolve around the screen simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b").animate({left: "+=500"}, 2000);
    $("#b").animate({top: "+=300"}, 1000);
    $("#b").animate({left: "-=500"}, 1000);
    $("#b").animate({top: "-=300"}, 1000);

});
</script>
<div id="b" style="position:absolute; top:50px">

<img src="img/codelab-1.jpg" width="200px"/></div>
```